# Using Delphi to fill out a table template made using a rich text (rtf) file

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a table in rtf (rich text format) file format.

I wonder if it is possible to place different content into the cells at runtime.

Here is a screenshot. Some blank fields need to be filled in with a value.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't really get it. You might want to elaborate a bit. You could also provide screenshots, a sample RTF file, etc.

Comment: Edit and print an RTF file? Just use TRichEdit. But this question is pretty much unanswerable and will attract close votes unless it is significantly improved.

Comment: Do you want to make a little miniature version of Microsoft Word with all its table editing and formatting features? You better get a little more specific.

Comment: so how do i create tables using TRichEdit?

Comment: You want to edit the cells of an RTF file (like the one above) using `TEdits` on a `TForm` in a Delphi application, do you? That is, in your form, you have `TLabel` controls with captions `Adi Soyadi`, `Adresi`, etc., and next to these are `TEdit` controls.

Comment: @All: Yes, the `TRichEdit` lacks in functionality. Editing tables is not possible (unless you go far beyond the VCL functionality).

Comment: yes they are in my form but i couldn t make alignment for printing. i tried TRichEdit.

Comment: Wait... "Printing"? Since when is this question about printing?!

Comment: RTF is not an appropriate format for editing forms.

Comment: yes, i just want to print some labels and TEdits with an order.

Comment: @user859104: Then draw to `Printer.Canvas` manually! That is extremely easy!

Comment: thanks for the replies! i ll try the code below.

Comment: Since user accepted an answer, I have edited his title and his question to be less confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote "Some blank fields need to be edited" - if this means that the RTF is some kind of template, where empty fields need to be filled in programmatically, here is what I would do:

- use your text editor to open the RTF document (OpenOffice or MS Word for example)
- insert special placeholder strings in the empty fields like $field1$, $field2$ ...
- save the document
- in your Delphi application, load the RTF into a string (using TStringlist for example)
- use Delphi String functions to find and replace the special placeholder strings with the actual values

Comment: Good idea, if that's what the OP wants. But the OP does seem to have difficulty explaining anything clearly.

Comment: you need to escape the text that you insert

Comment: I hope that my edits of the user's question make it at least fit his accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

To print a form on a sheet of paper, simply draw on the printer's canvas!

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  y, Margin, Col2: integer;
  LineHeight: integer;
begin
  with TPrintDialog.Create(nil) do
    try
      if not Execute then
        Exit;
    finally
      Free;
    end;

  Printer.BeginDoc;

  Printer.Title := 'Sample Form';
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Arial';
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Size := 11;

  Margin := 5*Printer.Canvas.TextWidth('M');
  Col2 := 35*Printer.Canvas.TextWidth('M');
  LineHeight := 3 * Printer.Canvas.TextHeight('M') div 2;

  y := Margin;

  Printer.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  Printer.Canvas.TextOut(MARGIN, y, 'Name: ');
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  Printer.Canvas.TextOut(Col2, y, 'Andreas Rejbrand');

  inc(y, LineHeight);

  Printer.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  Printer.Canvas.TextOut(MARGIN, y, 'Age: ');
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  Printer.Canvas.TextOut(Col2, y, '23');

  inc(y, LineHeight);

  Printer.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  Printer.Canvas.TextOut(MARGIN, y, 'Nationality: ');
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  Printer.Canvas.TextOut(Col2, y, 'Swedish');

  Printer.EndDoc;

end;
```

The result: http://privat.rejbrand.se/sampledrawing.pdf

Comment: The OP seems terribly confused to me. Do they have an Edit box or a Rich edit containing a table which is made up of cells which contain text?  Who can say...

Comment: @Warren P: True. My *guess* is that this is what he wants, though.

Comment: Well this is useful to later people who come along looking for help with printing, thus +1!

Answer (score 2):

To use existing RTF content in a TRichEdit, load it into the Text or Lines properties of the component:

```
RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile(rtfFilename);
```

-or-

```
RichEdit1.Text := StringILoadedFromAnRtfFileOnDisk;
```

I am not sure what you want to do (programmatically create a or modify a table based on some existing unspecified RTF content, print it, etc).  By asking about a rich edit, and also asking about a regular edit, it's very hard to understand.

You asked in a comment, how you can create tables in a TRichEdit:

```
procedure TForm1.PutTableIntoRichEdit;
begin
  RichEdit1.Text := '{\rtf1\ansi\deff0'#13#10+
'\trowd'#13#10+
'\cellx1000'#13#10+
'\cellx2000'#13#10+
'\cellx3000'#13#10+
'cell 1\intbl\cell'#13#10+
'cell 2\intbl\cell'#13#10+
'cell 3\intbl\cell'#13#10+
'\row'#13#10+
'}' ;
end;
```

If you want to use that RTF content in the screenshot you showed above, inside your delphi program, just load it up and try something, and ask a specific question.  Showing us a screenshot of microsoft word isn't helping your question be clear.

Comment: +1 for coding the RTF manually. However, I suspect this is not going to help the OP.

Comment: -1 "I want my program to edit and print an existing rtf file."

Comment: Modified answer. User also asked in a comment how to create a table.

Comment: ok, this approach could work with latest understanding of question